# Is onResume() called after onRequestPermissionsResult() in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I have an activity and i have put `checkSelfPermission` and `requestPermissions` methods in `onCreate` method.

I also have an `onRequestPermissionsResult` method outside of onCreate.

Finally i have an `onResume` method, too.

Which one is called first, `onResume` or `onRequestPermissionsResult`?

Comment: If you put `requestPermissions` in `onCreate()` ,  `onRequestPermissionsResult` will be called  before `onResume()`

Comment: What prevents you from doing some tests yourself? It would take just a few lines of code and much less time that writing question here and waiting for anyone to answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The correct chain of events is the following:

1. You call `requestPermissions` in the Activity's **onCreate**
2. `requestPermissions` start running in another thread, because it is
       designed to not block the UI thread. So your activity goes through **onStart** and then **onResume**
3. the request of the permission generates a dialog, which fires
       **onPause** on the Activity, because it is no more in foreground position.
4. The activity at this moment is paused and you can see a dialog
       asking to allow or deny the permission.
5. You make your choice, the dialog gets resolved and **onResume** is
       called on the Activity.

Also notice that the **onPause** is fired by the dialog always after **onStart** and **onResume** of the Activity, no matter how long it takes to execute the code in them.

And now you can also see why you shouldn't put requestPermissions in **onResume**.

Comment: I had the exact same question. Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: onstart and onresume might not be called at all - that's why calling requestPermissions in oncreate is wrong

Answer (score 4):

The first one is `onRequestPermissionsResult` !

I have destroy some object on `onPause()`, and It will be recreate on `onResume()`, but I find my `onRequestPermissionsResult()` operate some destroyed object and caused `NullPointEx`

Answer (score 2):

`onResume()` will be called first during the launch of your `Activity` as `onRequestPermissionsResult(...)` will only be called after user accepts or denies permission to application in Permission request dialog. But onResume again gets called after `onRequestPermissionsResult(...)` is called to allow your activity to take in account the user choice (granted or denied permission) and execute the code accordingly

Answer (score -5):

`onCreate` called first and only once when activity launched first time.

`onResume` called directly after `onCreate` or when activity return after pause.

And `onRequestPermissionsResult` called after user confirm permission.

Conclusion:`onResume` is called before `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

You can read about Activity LifeCycle https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Please mark as answered if it help.

Comment: Edited. Thanks @TimCastelijns

Comment: This answer is incorrect. onRequestPermissionsResult is called before onResume(). Have you tested on any device?

Comment: Do you have any source for this answer ? the document you pointed does not refer to the order of `onRequestPermissionRequest`

Comment: I've tested this and when onRequestPermissionsResult method ends, onResume is called again.